# What is the value of gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds?

Tags: xna, monogame

I was wondering what is exactly the value of `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` in a second? Please explain it to me completely and as great as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation [`ElapsedGameTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx) is:

> Property Value
>
> Elapsed game time since the last update.

This means it's the amount of time since the last time the update function was called. It's a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timespan%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Getting [`TotalSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timespan.totalseconds%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from a `TimeSpan` will give you the time in seconds. This is likely to be a pretty small value, since updates happen very fast.

Comment: So if my game has been running for 500 ms then this value will be equal to 0.5?

Comment: No, the update method is called many times in 500ms. If the game is running at 60 frames per second the value is likely to be 1 / 60 = 0.0166 seconds.

Comment: @MesutDarvishian If you are looking for that time interval that passed since the last frame, you really should just use `1./60.` ([fix your timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/))